# How do I center "search button" next to the search bar with CSS?

Tags: html, css, searchbar

I'm learning programming (web development), I started yesterday, I want to specifically center the **"search button"** *next* to the search bar, but for some reason it doesn't seem to work, may you help me, please?

**Here's an image of the problem and below my code lines.**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6S1T.png)

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Best Cookies: Buy the best chocolate cookies!</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <!--This is the website header-->
    <h1 id="Cookieland">Cookieland</h1>
    <div>
        <form action="#">
            <input type="text" class="search-input" placeholder="Search Cookies">
            <button type="submit" class="search-button">Search</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
h1 {
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: wheat;
    height: 70px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: auto;
}
body {
    background-color:black;
}
/* Styling for the search container */
.search-container {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
/* Styling for the search input */
.search-input {
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    width: 400px;
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
}
/* Styling for the search button */
.search-button {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    color: #333;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: background-color 0.3s;
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
}
/* Styling for the search button on hover */
.search-button:hover {
    background-color: #e0e0e0;
}
```

Comment: Your `.search-input` is a block. Meaning it'll take up the entire rest of the width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked your code, It seems like you've applied the display: block; property to both the search input and the search button, which causes them to stack on top of each other, taking up the full width of the container. To center them horizontally next to each other, you need to wrap them in a container and apply appropriate CSS. Like, we dont need to put margin: auto, Since we want the search input and search button to be displayed next to each other, we don't need to center them horizontally using. The code might be like below,

```css
h1 {
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: wheat;
    height: 70px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: auto;
}
body {
    background-color: black;
}
/* Styling for the search container */
.search-container {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
/* Styling for the search input */
.search-input {
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    width: 400px;
}
/* Styling for the search button */
.search-button {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    color: #333;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: background-color 0.3s;
}
/* Styling for the search button on hover */
.search-button:hover {
    background-color: #e0e0e0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Best Cookies: Buy the best chocolate cookies!</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <!--This is the website header-->
    <h1 id="Cookieland">Cookieland</h1>
    <div class="search-container">
        <form action="#">
            <input type="text" class="search-input" placeholder="Search Cookies">
            <button type="submit" class="search-button">Search</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some changes to your code,

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Best Cookies: Buy the best chocolate cookies!</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <!--This is the website header-->
    <h1 id="Cookieland">Cookieland</h1>
    <div>
        <form class="search-container" action="#">
            <input type="text" class="search-input" placeholder="Search Cookies">
            <button type="submit" class="search-button">Search</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
h1 {
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: wheat;
    height: 70px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: auto;
}
body {
    background-color:black;
}
/* Styling for the search container */
.search-container {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
/* Styling for the search input */
.search-input {
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    width: 400px;
    margin: auto;
    display: inline-block;
}
/* Styling for the search button */
.search-button {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    color: #333;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: background-color 0.3s;
    margin: auto;
    display: inline-block;
}
/* Styling for the search button on hover */
.search-button:hover {
    background-color: #e0e0e0;
}
```

For below output,
[image]

Just made changes to the display property of input and button tag to `inline-block` and added this `search-container` existing class to form tag

Hope that would help you.